# Galaxy S4 outside Europe

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sim-unlocking

I have a Galaxy S4 bought today in Europe. Also I have a SIM card from Orange and everything works fine here.

But I discovered that there could be a kind of lock if I try to use another SIM card from another country outside Europe.

More precisely, I live in South America and I'd like to know if that lock still remains or if Samsung changed the rules.

I'm going home in 3 months.

Has anybody here tried to use it with another SIM outside Europe?